# How to track all events on react-native app with azure application insights as it's done on react?

Tags: react-native, azure-application-insights

I have an application that has web and mobile versions. On web version I'm using a code similar to this example to track all events (page views and api calls) without track those events one by one: 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/application-insights-react-demo

This can be done using this specially because of component withAITracking that only exists for react version of this plugin: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS

When trying to use the "same" code on a react-native app I'm receiving an error: TypeError: Prototype value can only be an object or null.

Does anyone knows if it's possible to track the events on a react-native app without code all pageViews and other events by hand one by one?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a way to do that?